# Javascript DOMParser; XML with special characters

Tags: javascript, xml, domparser

I am trying to parse an XML string using the DOMParser.

The XML-string has a node with an atrribute containing the string `&#xa;`. I want to read the value of this attribute as a string, but it does not work since the DOMParser reads `&#xa;` as a single special character and not as a string of characters.

In other words, in my XML-string I have a node something like this:

`<nodename attributename="&#xa;"/>`

Using the DOMParser I am trying to read the value of the attribute like this:

`var attributevalue = xmlNode.attributes[0].nodeValue;`

and get `attributevalue` to contain the string `&#xa;` instead of a single special character.

Any tips on how to do this?
Thanks in advance for any help!